# Fig doesn't link two containers

Tags: docker, boot2docker, fig

Long story short: `fig up` doesn't link 2 containers properly when `docker run`does.

**Scenario:**

There are 2 containers: one with Cassandra, another with client service. When containers start Client expects to have `cassandra` hostname in hosts file and be able to reach it's 9042 port.

I use docker's links to tight containers together. Here is a `fig.yml`:

```
cassandra:
  image: "myrepo/cassandra"
  ports:
    - "7199:7199"
    - "9042:9042"
    - "9160:9160"
    - "61621:61621"
    - "2222:22"
  hostname: cassandra

client:
  image: myrepo/client
  links:
    - cassandra
  ports:
    - "8098:8098"
    - "8099:8099"
  hostname: client
```

When I do `fig up client`, fig starts cassandra, then client but client cannot reach the cassandra container (it can ping it, but cannot reach the 9042 port).

However, if I start cassandra with `fig up cassandra` and then run:

`docker run --link tramm_cassandra_1:cassandra --link tramm_cassandra_1:cassandra_1 --link tramm_cassandra_1:tramm_cassandra_1 -p 8098:8098 -p 8099:8099 myrepo/client`

then client can communicate with cassandra without a problem.

I've inspected containers and here are the output:
- [cassandra inspect](http://ttps://gist.github.com/DimaSalakhov/30aabc5d5868b8d48c40)
- [fig up client inspect](https://gist.github.com/DimaSalakhov/ce8cc48d4169391339be)
- [docker run client inspect](https://gist.github.com/DimaSalakhov/d921d1432a582269b904)

The only difference I can find is in `HostConfig -> Devices` and `HostConfig -> LxcConf`. In fig-up version they are equal to `null`, in docker-run version - to `[]`.

Can somebody explain a difference between `fig up` and `docker run` and why it works in 'native' docker scenario and doesn't in fig.

Comment: It's probably because cassandra takes a lot of time to actually start listening on the port. Try `fig up cassandra`, wait for a while, and then `fig up --no-recreate client`.

Comment: That was a brilliant idea. I though I've checked this scenario before when I injected delay on client's startup, but `--no-recreate` flag did a better job. (thumbsup). Will you agree to add it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Glad it helped. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because cassandra takes a lot of time to actually start listening on the port. Try `fig up cassandra`, wait for a while, and then `fig up --no-recreate client`.

See also:

[Proposal: Containers should not be considered started until the TCP ports they expose are open](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7445)

[Is there a way to delay container startup to support dependant services with a longer startup time](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/374)